# Pipenv and setup.py workflow

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, pipenv

I am developing a package `Pkg-1` in Python and my workflow is as follows:

I use `pipenv` to install a dependency `A` of `Pkg-1` with `pipenv install A` and then I install `Pkg-1` with `pipenv install -e .`

Now I want to use `Pkg-1` in another package I develop, `Pkg-2`. I want to install `Pkg-1` from github with a command like `pipenv install ssh://git@github.com/user/Pkg1.git`. At this point I need a `setup.py` in `Pkg-1` with all the requirements fixed to the versions in `Pipfile.lock`. I create one with [pipenv-setup](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv-setup/).

The problem with this approach is the following:

Assume that `Pkg-1` depends on the package `A` that depends on `B` with a restriction on the version of `B` >=3. This will install the latest version of `B`, assume it is 4. Running `pipenv-setup` will pin the version of `B` in the `setup.py`. Now you want to install a package `C` (as a dependency on `Pkg-1`) that depends on `B` with the restriction on the version <=3.5. Normally, `pipenv` would be able to resolve this dependency. But since the version of `B` is pinned for `Pkg-1` in the `setup.py`, `pipenv` will complain.

Do you have any suggestions? Is there something wrong with my workflow?